# Uniqueness of the Greens function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I'm a little confused about the interpretation of the Greens function. My understanding is that the Greens function is related to the solution of differential equations, so it should be unique.

For a linear  second order homogeneous ODE with separated boundary conditions we can write the Greens function as 
$$G(x,x_0)= \begin{cases}
\frac{u_1(x)u_2(x_o)}{p_2(x_0)W(x_0)},\quad x<x_0 \\
\frac{u_1(x_0)u_2(x)}{p_2(x_0)W(x_0)}, \quad x>x_0
   \end{cases}$$
where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions of the ODE satisfying the left and right boundary conditions respectively, $p_2(x)$ is the polynomial multiplying the second derivative term and $W(x)$ is the Wronskian.

Here's where I'm getting confused. For linear homogeneous ODEs the Wronskian isn't unique, in this case it's given by 
$$W(x) = C\exp\left[-\int^x p_1(s) ds\right]$$
where $p_1(x)$ is the polynomial multiplying the first derivative term and $C$ is an arbitrary integration constant.

Doesn't this mean the Greens function isn't unique (since it depends on $W(x)$)?

Comment: Irrelevant note: it's "Green function," similar to Bessel function, Legendre polynomial, Hermite function, etc.. It sounds wrong because of the color, but it's not Green's function, and not Greens function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wronskian $$W=u_1u_2'-u_1'u_2$$ is calculated with respect to the same solutions $u_1,u_2$ that are used to define the Green function. This corresponds to a specific value of the constant $C$ and ensures uniqueness.